# angular edit each post in array

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I have an array of posts:

```
.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: [
        {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
        {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
        {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15}
    ]
  };
  return o;
}])
```

and a Controller. I would like to edit all upvotes when clicking a button, so I have the following.

```
angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(title){
    $scope.posts.push({
            title: "ja"
    });
});
```

but obviously this is creating new posts. anyone knows how to edit the existing ones?
thanks

Comment: pos[index].title ='ja'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the upvotes value of all posts on clicking a button you would have to change your forEach to:

```
angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(post){
    post.upvotes++;
});
```

But if it was to be only a specifc one called 'ja' then you would need to so something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(post){
    if (post.title === 'ja') {
        post.upvotes++;
    }
});
```

Comment: was looking more for this `angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(post){ post.upvotes = 5; });` but you answered my question. thanks for the help